# Collada plugin for Blender missing?

Tags: blender

I've installed Blender, version 2.58.0 that comes with Ubuntu 11.10, Everything works fine but I can't export to .dae (Collada).

It seems Blender 2.5x comes with the exporter plug-in already, however it's not there.  I'm running Ubuntu in an AMD 64 bits.

I did try to install the plug-in from the [Collada website](http://colladablender.illusoft.com/cms/), but without success. How can I install the plug-in or make Blender find it?

Answer (score 1):

Known defect in Ubuntu.

Blender 2.67b on Windows 7 - Collada exporter present and works.
Blender 2.67b on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - Collada exporter does not appear in Blender Export menu.

Ref: [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blender/+bug/1058777),
Reported in September 2012.
Still broken in July 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is a possible workaround for you, but [gamedev suggests to convert collada files into FBX and import those](https://www.gamedev.net/topic/615383-importing-collada-into-blender-25/).

Comment: Another fix (pointed out in the bug report) is that you can just download Blender from the website and use that. I had the same issue, downloaded it manually, and the plugin is now there.